# How to sort a data in array of object from graphQL server?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I am using GraphQl and below is my data

```
{
  "data": {
    "food": {
      "category": [
        {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "meat"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "brink"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "vegetable"
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "name": "bread"
        },
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "cookie"
        },
        {
          "id": -1,
          "name": "candy"
        },

      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How can I sort this when I execute the query and the return data will be like below

```
    {
  "data": {
    "food": {
      "category": [
        {
          "id": -1,
          "name": "candy"
        },
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "cookie"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "vegetable"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "brink"
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "meat"
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "name": "bread"
        }, 
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I try

```
 {
      food {
        category(orderBy: id_ASC){
            id
            name
        }
  }
}
```

but show

> unknown argument "orderBy" on field "category" of type Food.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: i think the orderBy field is not a standard field of graphql. you must find out how the orderBy or sorting should be done on your API. do you know which server side graphql library is used on your API.

Comment: Can you post some of the code you're using on the server to resolve the 'food' query? As @InusSaha said, you'll need to update the resolver for that query to accept an orderBy argument, and sort based on that. GraphQL doesn't inherently support sorting.